# How to debug emacs lisp? (e.g. Symbol's value as variable is void: n)

Tags: init-file, debugging, debug, debug-on-error

When I start Emacs, I get the error message: `Symbol's value as variable is void: n`
I am pretty sure, it is just a typo in my init.el, but how can I find it?

Shouldn't there be a debugger, which tells me exactly where this variable `n` shows up?

My question is, whether it exists, and if it exists, where it is?

I would also appreciate best practices for debugging the init.el (or elisp in general) and also resources to learn this.

I loaded emacs with `--debug-init` and the backtrace gives me:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable n)
load-with-code-conversion("/home/xx/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/xx/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
load("/home/xx/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xfb4a62eb1ee4990>)   #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c686ddc0ca9b5>) t)
command-line()
normal-top-level()
```

Which is unhelpful. What does it try to communicate to me?

Comment: I added a random `n` at top level of one of the files that I load when I
start emacs and then I invoked emacs with `emacs --debug-init`. I got
the following message: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable n)
eval-buffer(#<buffer *load*-97476> nil "/some/path/org-config.el" nil
t) ; Reading at buffer position 32678`. Opening the file and going to
position 32678 (with `M-g c 32678`) took me directly to the errant `n`.
I don't understand why the buffer position is missing from your backtrace. Did you leave it out by any chance?

Comment: @NickD: That position comes from `backtrace--print-func-and-args` (since 27.1) and from the comments is specific to `eval-buffer` usage -- which *is* happening in your case, but seemingly not for Sinthoras.  Maybe `load` is doing something slightly different in different versions/cases?

Comment: Yes, maybe - the OP can perhaps add to the question the Emacs version they are running.

Comment: I am on Emacs 27.1. 
And I did not leave out that line on my backtrace (since it was one of the points of the question, how I can make it show up, such that the computer tells me where the errant is, and I don't have to search it by myself.)

Answer (score 1):

> I would also appreciate best practices for debugging the init.el (or elisp in general) and also resources to learn this.

In a case like this, I'd say start by bisecting your init file. Use command `comment-region` to comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... of your init file, to find the culprit. With `C-u` it uncomments, instead of comments, the region.

If you want, if you've narrowed the problem down to some function (something within that function is causing the problem), then use `M-x debug-on-entry` for that function.

That opens the debugger for each invocation of that function. Step through the debugger with `d` (or `c` to skip diving down inside a function). You'll see exactly what's going on and what goes wrong.

---

That said, there are ***lots*** of questions on this site about `Symbol's value as a variable is void`. Try searching for that on the site, to see if your question is a duplicate. If it is, please delete it.

Comment: Before posting, I already searched on this site about my question, and was surprised that I did not find it. The questions I found were all quite specific about specific `Symbol's value as a variable is void` errors, while I am asking about general principles.

Comment: Good. Thanks for searching.